# Importing comments from Facebook App to Wordpress

Tags: facebook

I know there is a plugin to put facebook comment app into Wordpress, which automatically merge the comments. The problem is that I installed the plugin hard-code style, so I don't have any plugin page on Wordpress, I just check the comments with the moderator tool at facebook. Now I don't want it anymore, and I'm not finding a way to export the comments to wordpress. Tried this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-import-comments/ but doens't work, doesn't event my App ID. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try Facebook for SEO - it should import them into your database (just noticed that it won't import the user pic with the comment, but it worked on mine). I was using the social media plugin for Facebook comments using the FB developers app.